# Can't create a database using PostgreSql with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm a junior web developer trying to develop my first Ruby on Rails project. I'm following this guide to deploy the app on render.com.

However, after installing rails and following this command to create a database (I'm on Ubuntu):

```
rails db:create
```

I come across this problem in command window:

```
We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

        bin/rails db:create
Couldn't create 'mysite_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

        bin/rails db:create


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

It says we couldnt find your database. But I have it in config/database.yml:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem "pg"
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: mysite_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: mysite

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: mysite_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: mysite_production
  username: mysite
  password: <%= ENV["MYSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

What should I do? I'm going crazy over this.

I tried a different command:

```
        bin/rails db:create
```

also didn't work.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you're running the app inside a docker container? If so you might have missed the steps needed to install the postgres image and start the postgres service in the container.

Comment: This might be a Rails bug. Can someone else confirm? I've opened it up in the Issues tab in the Rails project. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46577

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As default you are logged in as default user, That so this error happen. To resolve this error you have to logged in as a postgres user and create user with your username.

```
sudo su -postgres
```

then hit enter. then you will be logged in as a postgres user

```
creatuser -s -r username
```

then after you can switch back into default browser, to switch back hit ***ctrl+D***
then you can create database

```
rails db:create
```

vist this to get more know about this error https://www.udemy.com/course/professional-rails-5-development-course/learn/lecture/10575320#overview

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the server is not running.

Did you:

- Install the PostgreSQL packages?
- Start the server?  Try running:
  `sudo systemctl start postgresql`

Comment: `/var/run/` implies that the app is running in a docker container so I'm not so sure `sudo systemctl start postgresql` is the correct solution.

Comment: @max why not make it an answer :)

Comment: Because its merely a hypothesis. @Luckyfella

Comment: I actually tried that, so I can weigh in. My postgres was running. The other rake commands were working fine, too. Yet this issue still occurred specifically with db:create. There is a small chance that, given the recency of this issue & the fact that I too was surprised by it, that this is a bug in Rails itself.

Answer (score -2):

`EDIT: Probably not the right answer for most people, since it seems to be a DB connection issue for OP. But this did catch me out. Hopefully someone else with the same circumstances as I can find this thread helpful in the future.`

First off, welcome to the industry & best of luck on your junior journey!

I had this exact same problem just recently, and did a deep dive into the gems to debug the issue.

### Root cause

I haven't looked too closely after solving the problem, but to me it seems Rails 7 might be treating `database.yml` somewhat differently from previous versions of Rails (?). Or maybe the `database.yml` we are both using is messed up straight from the source. To be honest, not sure.

Either way, the problem is this passage:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

ActiveRecord is treating `default` as an environment all on its own, at the same level as `development`, `test` and `production`

Which means that, when you run `rails db:create`, there's a connection going out for `development`, `test`, `production`.... and then one more time for `default`

And since the `database` name is not set on `default`, ActiveRecord is intelligently using the default database for postgres... which happens to be called `postgres`

### Solution

Simply remove the `default` config. I kind of like the `&default` / `<<: *default` pattern, so what I did was combine the `default` and `development` environments like so:

```
development: &default
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: mysite_development
```

That made everything work fine.

### Final file

(Note: Untested. I am using my own config.)

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem "pg"
#

development: &default
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: mysite_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: mysite

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: mysite_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: mysite_production
  username: mysite
  password: <%= ENV["MYSITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Comment: Sorry but this answer is just nonsense. There has not been any changes to the YAML parser or how Rails treats environments in Rails 7. `default:` is just a hash in the database config thats not actually used for anything and `&:default` is a YAML anchor. `<<: *default` then expands that anchor into the other hashes. I have no idea what was wrong with your app but its certainly not what you think and having every environment inherit from dev is just bad advice. I mean if you really want to use a key thats not `default` you could have literally chosen anything else.

Comment: If this actually were true don't you think someone would have reacted when `rails new foo -- database=postgresql` produced broken settings?

Comment: I'm sorry if you took this as unfriendly but this answer doesn't actually stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: @max That does not explain what I saw on my local. Also, what offended me was how you started. "Sorry but this answer is just nonsense" is likely to trigger a defensive reaction in anyone; doubly so on the internet.

Comment: This might be a bug. Can someone else confirm? I've opened it up in the Issues tab in the Rails project. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46577

Comment: No - this isn't a reproducable bug. You can see [how Rails loads database configurations in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/activerecord/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb#L45) which makes it easy to disprove the hypothesis that some unspecified change made rails treat "default" as an environment. That would break an enormous amount of Rails apps and cause an uproar. As to whats actually wrong with your app - maybe you set `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` or `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` to cause the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Its also irrelvant to the question here as the error is a connection error meaning that Rails can even reach the host. There is no host specified in the config so Rails will try to connect to PG via a unix socket. IF you had the same error and "fixed" it with this hacky solution then my guess it that you weren't running PG and then actually started it and then came to the falsy conclusion that this is what fixed the problem.

Comment: I see your point. However, could you please try doing the reproduction steps listed in the ticket, just for closure? EDIT: I see that you did on the Github issue. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I added a comment into the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46577#issuecomment-1348884004) with a request for some further details to run `bin/rails runner "pp ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.configs_for"` for debugging output.